# Trying to make inheritance with sprites and textures in SFML

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, sfml

I seem to have a problem when I am trying to inherit my sf::Sprite and sf::Texture from my base class to my subclass. It kind of works when I try to send the sprite and texture as an copy, but I will of course not get any image then. Do you have any idea how I can fix this problem? My base class:

```
#ifndef OBJECTHOLDER_H
#define OBJECTHOLDER_H
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>
using namespace std;

class ObjectHolder : public sf::Drawable {

private:
    float windowHeight;
    float windowWidth;
    sf::Texture texture;
    sf::Sprite sprite;
public:
    ObjectHolder();
    virtual ~ObjectHolder();
    float getWindowHeight() const;
    float getWindowWidth() const;
    const sf::Sprite & getSprite() const;
    const sf::Texture & getTexture() const;
};

#endif //OBJECTHOLDER_H

#include "ObjectHolder.h"

ObjectHolder::ObjectHolder() {
    float windowHeight;
    float windowWidth;
}

ObjectHolder::~ObjectHolder() {
}

float ObjectHolder::getWindowHeight() const {
    return this->windowHeight;
}

float ObjectHolder::getWindowWidth() const {
    return this->windowWidth;
}

const sf::Sprite & ObjectHolder::getSprite() const {
    return this->sprite;
}

const sf::Texture & ObjectHolder::getTexture() const {
    return this->texture;
}
```

My subclass:

```
#ifndef PROJECTILE_H
#define PROJECTILE_H
#include "ObjectHolder.h"

class Projectile : public ObjectHolder {
public:
    Projectile();
    virtual ~Projectile();
    void move(const sf::Vector2f& amount);
    virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const;
};

#endif //PROJECTILE_H

#include "Projectile.h"
#include <iostream>

Projectile::Projectile() {
    if (!this->getTexture().loadFromFile("../Resources/projectile.png")) { 
        cout << "Error! Projectile sprite could not be loaded!" << endl;
    }
    this->getSprite().setTexture(getTexture());
    this->getSprite().setPosition(sf::Vector2f(940.0f, 965.0f));
}

Projectile::~Projectile() {
}

void Projectile::move(const sf::Vector2f & amount) {
    this->getSprite().move(amount);
}

void Projectile::draw(sf::RenderTarget & target, sf::RenderStates states) const{
    target.draw(this->getSprite(), states);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just mark those members as `protected` rather than `private`, which allows your derived classes to access them directly:

```
class Base {
protected:
    sf::Texture m_Texture;
}

class Derived : public Base {
    Derived() {
        m_Texture.loadFromFile("myTexture.png");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it worked. Thank you! I can not believe it was so easy. I have been sitting and switching from const and call values for a very long time now. I did not think of protected as an option.